# Detecting if html form was successful or errored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to submit a post request to my backend which returns a pdf. I was wondering if there is a way to detect errors and successful responses from the backend.

I created the form using:

```
form = $document.createElement("form")).attr({"method":"POST", "action":"myurl"});
$(document.createElement('input')).attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'data', 'value': data}).appendTo(form);
form.appendTo( document.body ).submit()
```

How do I change this to have a success callback or error call back while still using the form submission because I know this can be accomplished using $.ajax and sending a regular post request.

Comment: You can't. The page refreshes with the submit and all content before is gone.

Comment: @epascarello incorrect. see my answer. you can use a target and iframe.

Comment: @DonRhummy Where is the iframe in the code above? And the code is returning a pdf...there is no webpage....

Comment: @epascarello As indicated in my answer, you can add an iframe dynamically via JavaScript. And the PDF can be opened as the response instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Using Ajax to submit the post
2. Using an iframe where the iframe returns some javascript code that calls a parent method

For the 2nd choice, you'll need to set the form's target to the name of the iframe:

```
form.target = myIframe.getAttribute( "name" );
```

It will then be submitted into that iframe (which you can create and put into the document via javascript).

The iframe should then return an HTML page that has javascript calling the parent frame's method:

```
...include all the regular HTML code...
<script>
    window.parent.MyResponseHandler.response( "ok" );
</script>
```

In the parent frame, you need to create that handler:

```
var MyResponseHandler = {
    response: function(res) {
        alert( res );
    }
}
```

**EDIT: If you want to return a PDF on response, you can do this in two ways:**

1. Have the response JavaScript open the PDF in a new window
2. If it's returning the PDF as the page's data, use the server-side code to return the PDF on success - which will result in it opening in the browser - or the above code for an error.

Comment: but now you have a disconnect between the data posted and the PDF that likely relies on that data to be generated

Comment: @charlietfl that can be accounted for, see the edit.

Comment: Oh I know it can be accounted for, but it was worth mentioning and I'm not so sure your explanations aren't an oversimplification

Comment: How would an error be detected using the iframe method? my example can display the pdf as is. I just can't detect an error

Comment: @k.ken the server side code would output the PDF if ok, but output the javascript code that calls the response function and pass the error into there.